# How to access static method from ExpressJS App Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have a server built with ExpressJS. Now, I wish to access my socket io instance from anywhere in my app after initialization, so I tried keeping it in a static method.

But, whenever I invoke the static method I keep getting this error:

> AppServer.getServerSocket is not a function

Here is my code:

```
const ServerSocket = require('./sockets/server_socket');

class AppServer {

    constructor() {
        this.initServerSocket(server);
    }
    
    initServerSocket(server) {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(server);
    }

    static getServerSocket() { //Whenever I invoke this I keep getting the error: AppServer.getServerSocket is not a function
        return this.serverSocket;
    }
    
    start() {
        const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
        server.listen(port, function () {
            console.log(`Server running on port ${port} in ${app.get("env")} mode`);
        });
    }
}


let appServer = new AppServer();
appServer.start();

module.exports = AppServer;
```

Here is how I tried accessing it in another file

```
...
const AppServer = require('../server');

function emitEvent(event){
  AppServer.getServerSocket().io.emit(event); //Error, AppServer.getServerSocket is not a function
}
```

How can I resolve this, please?

Comment: You're attempting to access an instance property via a static method. Only class properties are accessible that way. How about exporting the instance as the default export and then accessing the instance property everywhere?

Comment: A static method does not have access to any `this` that is an instance of the class and it is NOT on the prototype of an instance - it's on the class itself.  That's the whole purpose of a `static` method.  It does not depend upon or use an instance of the class.  So, you should probably make your `getServerSocket()` method NOT be static and call it on an instance.

Comment: Regardless if the code should work or not, `AppServer.getServerSocket` should be a function see: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-diffie-c9xpc?file=/src/index.js. if you can't debug try using `console.log(typeof AppServer.getServerSocket)` to check out what `require('../server')` is.